# setMaximumTintColor in iOS 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

I want to be able to set the max and min tint color in iOS 4, how to do this? Is there a hack to do so? Here's the code in iOS 5:

```
[self.fontSize_ setMaximumTrackTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [self.fontSize_ setMinimumTrackTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

Comment: Tint color isn't something that usually has a maximum or minimum, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Ah. The word 'Track' was important there. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tintColor` methods are new in iOS 5. But you can use `-[UISlider setMinimumTrackImage:forState:]` and `[UISlider setMaximumTrackImage:forState:]` all the way back to iOS 2.0; you'll just have to use stretchable images instead of a tint color.